# Tomcat - How to specify properties that can be expanded in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, configuration, properties, server.xml

Currently, I have in my server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

I want it to become:

```
<Connector port="${oms.ui.port}" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

I put this property oms.ui.port in a property file residing in apache-tomcat-7.0.8\lib
but it does not find it, I get:

> WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting
>   property 'port' to '${oms.ui.port}' did not find a matching property.

Maybe someone with a better Tomcat experience can help me, please?

Comment: There is nothing in the Tomcat documentation to suggest that such a thing is supported.

Comment: @BorisHamanov were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 19):

According to [Tomcat 7.0 Configuration Overview](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/index.html):

> Apache Ant-style variable substitution is supported; a system property with the name propname may be used in a configuration file using the syntax ${propname}. All system properties are available including those set using the -D syntax, those automatically made available by the JVM and those configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

So you can use either a JVM system property or `catalina.properties` to declare your variable and assign a value to it.

Comment: I never knew about this until now and so traditionally, for multiple tomcat instances of a similar app, had to manually change the server.xml and context.xml files. This feature is awesome!

Comment: You can also configure it to use system envs - see property [org.apache.tomcat.util.digester. PROPERTY_SOURCE](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html)